# Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent - after error within an updatepanel

Tags: asp.net, http-headers, updatepanel

I'm getting the following error: Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent. I have looked around online, including some of the SO questions with exactly this error, but none have resolved my issue. Here is my particular scenario:

I have an asp.net gridview that is inside of an update panel (which also happens to be inside of a modalpopupextender). The gridview has a template field with an imagebutton that, when clicked, downloads a PDF. All works well until I run into an error trying to download. I handle the error inside the Gridview.RowCommand event, and the page doesn't change back on the client like I want. *However*, if I click the download again, the file doesn't download, and I catch the error inside ScriptManager.AsyncPostBackError event "Server cannot set content type after HTTP headers have been sent." Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

--Default.aspx--

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdnHiddenField" runat="server" />
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="hdnHiddenField_mpeModalPopup" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="hdnHiddenField"
    CancelControlID="lnkClose" PopupControlID="pnlPanel" BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground"></cc1:ModalPopupExtender>
<asp:Panel ID="pnlPanel" runat="server" BorderStyle="Double" Width="50%" Height="75%" CssClass="modalPopup" style="overflow: auto; display: none">
    <div class="modalHeaderClose">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkClose" runat="server" Text="Close [X]"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <cc1:Accordion ID="accdnPolicyInfo" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0" RequireOpenedPane="false">
        <Panes>
            <cc1:AccordionPane ID="accpnlDocuments" runat="server">
                <Header>
                    <div class="accordionHeader">Documents</div>
                </Header>
                <Content>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDocuments" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div style="text-align: center; padding: 0 10px 10px 10px;">
                                <asp:GridView ID="gvGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True">
                                    <Columns>                                       
                                        <asp:TemplateField>
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="imgDownloadPDF" runat="server" 
                                                    CommandArgument='<%# Bind("ImageKey") %>' CommandName="DownloadDocument" 
                                                    ImageUrl="~/images/PDF-download.png" ToolTip="Download file to your computer" />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EmptyDataRowStyle ForeColor="Red" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                                </asp:GridView>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel> 
                </Content>
            </cc1:AccordionPane>
        </Panes>                
    </cc1:Accordion>            
</asp:Panel>
```

--Default.aspx.vb--

```
Private Sub gvPolicyDocs_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvPolicyDocs.RowDataBound
    Dim imgDownloadPDF As ImageButton = e.Row.FindControl("imgDownloadPDF")
    If imgDownloadPDF IsNot Nothing Then
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(imgDownloadPDF)  
        'I just tried changing to RegisterAsyncPostBackControl method and found that I receive the same error even on the first attempt
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvPolicyDocs_RowCommand(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvPolicyDocs.RowCommand
    Try
        StreamPDF(e.CommandArgument, False)
    Catch ex As Exception
        ErrorHandler.HandleError(ex)    'sends out an email and returns back; ErrorHandler is an object I created
    End Try
    hdnHiddenField_mpeModalPopup.Show()    'otherwise modal popup disappears after return from postback
End Sub

Private Sub StreamPDF(ByVal strImageKey As String)
    Dim dtImagePaths As DataTable
    Dim oPDFManager As New PdfManager   'from ASPPDF library
    Dim bytes() As Byte
    Dim strImagePath As String = String.Empty

    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strImageKey) Then
        Throw New Exception("Invalid Image Key")
    End If

    'Get image path from database
    ...
    ...

    strImagePath = dtImagePaths.Rows(0).Item("ImagePath")
    bytes = oPDFManager.OpenDocument(strImagePath).SaveToMemory()   
    'I checked that on the run after the error, bytes contains exactly what I want - so when I write it to a file locally, I can see the PDF

    With Current
        .Response.BufferOutput = False  'tried true and false
        .Response.Clear()
        .Response.ClearContent()
        .Response.ClearHeaders()
        .Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        .Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("{0}; filename={1}.pdf", IIf(bDownloadFile, "attachment", "inline"), strImageKey))
        .Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", bytes.Length)
        .Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)
        .Response.Flush()
        .Response.Close()
        'Response.End()     '--> See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629
        .ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The UpdatePanel is probably the problem here.

Please see here.

[Why won't Response.Write() export a CSV file to the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19645651/why-wont-response-write-export-a-csv-file-to-the-browser)

Comment: I get that. And I already have my imagebutton set to do a full postback. And it always works if there is no error encountered. The question is, why is the error messing things up for the next request and how do I resolve it while still keeping the update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in case anyone else runs into this issue, [this article](https://bhuvanram.wordpress.com/) helped me out completely. It basically indicates that you can't download and use the asyncpostback functionality (via UpdatePanel) on the same page. It demonstrates a workaround in which all of the download code is done on an entirely separate page, and that page is opened in a hidden iframe on the current page. On a side note, if you are also or instead trying to open the pdf in a new window, the same workaround applies but instead of adding an iframe to the current page, you can call window.open() in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

So, I'm not sure how to fix this in VB, but I know the cause of this issue in C# as I have just had to deal with this issue myself.

The problem lies with the button itself. You need to register the button with the ScriptManager. You cannot do this at the `PageLoad()` event, you actually have to add an `OnInit` event to the button and add the registration there.

Example in C#:

ASP page code:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgDownloadPDF" runat="server" onInit="imgDownloadPDF_Init" ... />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void imgDownloadPDF_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(imgDownloadPDF);
}
```

I hope this helps.